# How to set multiple alarms firing distinct notifications for each in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alarmmanager

I am trying to develop an application in which the user can create more than 1 alarms for the same time ,say, 09:48. And for this time, each alarm has to create its own notification which leads the user to an activity when the notification is clicked. The other alarms which were scheduled at the same time must keep ringing until their notifications are clicked. Now, I am able to create alarms for different times and get their corresponding notifications which lead to an activity in which the user can dismiss or snooze the alarm. However, when I schedule more than one alarm for the same time, only 1 alarm is ringing and the other one gets lost. I share my code pieces at the below.

```
public void schedule(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);


    PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmId, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    alarmManager.setExact(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            alarmPendingIntent
    );
```

In my broadcastReceiver class:

```
    private void startAlarmService(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intentService = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "DEBUG", "************Alarm Broadcast Receiver**********");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context.startForegroundService(intentService);
    } else {
        context.startService(intentService);
    }
}
```

In my AlarmService :

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarm);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, RingActivity.class);
    int requestCode = new Random().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, notificationIntent, 0);

    //String alarmTitle = String.format("%s Alarm", intent.getStringExtra(TITLE));

    int notificationId = new Random().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, String.valueOf(notificationId))
            .setContentTitle("PASS1")
            .setContentText("PASS2")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pill)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    mediaPlayer.start();

    long[] pattern = { 0, 100, 1000 };
    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);

    startForeground(1, notification);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    mediaPlayer.stop();
    vibrator.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this code

```
startForeground(1, notification);
```

you are using 1 as the id.

If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

So the second alarm notification with the same id (because you are using a fixed value of 1) is replacing the old one